# How to use rails-i18n with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I went through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html and set up my `en.yml` file:

```
en:
  test:
    welcome: Welcome!!!
  registration:
    signup: Sign up for an invite!!
```

However, in my `new.html.haml` file,
How do I reference `signup`?

The tutorial only shows how to do so using ERB, not HAML. I tried this and it didn't work:

```
%h2 <%=t :registration.signup %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked once I did this:

change en.yml

```
  registration:
    signup: "Sign up for an invite to join CorkLabs!!!"
```

in .haml file

```
%h2= t 'registration.signup'
```

Comment: You should string escape all your YAML

Answer (score 10):

You should probably read the [HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html) to understand how HAML works. To add code to generate content for a tag, you use **=**, as in:

```
%h2= t('registration.signup')
```

Answer (score 3):

**app/views/registration/index.html.haml**

```
%h2
  =t('.signup')
```

**en.yml:**

```
en:
  registration:
    index:
      signup: Sign up for an invite!!
```

**NB:**

1. Rails path to the view must match YAML path to the symbol
2. There is a dot before `.signup`. Read more about [lazy lookups](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations)

Answer (score -1):

Other comments here relay how you can do this. For what it's worth though, you can also check out [haml-i18n-extractor](http://github.com/shaiguitar/haml-i18n-extractor#readme). It's a tool that helps with the string interpolation you need to extract from the templates automatically instead of needing to do things by hand. Should save you a bunch of time.