# Weird issue with i18n rails haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rails-i18n

I was looking into [How to use rails-i18n with HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948333/how-to-use-rails-i18n-with-haml) to find out how i18n works together with haml but ran into an issue I can't figure out.

This works:

**en.yml**

```
en:
  sitename: "Happy Sunday"
```

**new.haml**

```
%h1= t("sitename")
```

When I change the yml to

**en.yml**

```
en:
  home:
    sitename: "Happy Sunday"
```

**new.haml**

```
%h1= t("home.sitename")
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise/sessions#new
    Showing 
..../devise/sessions/new.html.haml where line #20 raised:

syntax error on line 4, col 6: `    home:'
Extracted source (around line #20):

17:       = flash[:alert]
18: .row
19:   .headline.pagination-centered
20:     %h1= t("home.sitename")
21:     %h2= t("slogan")
22: .row.headline.pagination-centered
23:   %a{:href => "/tour"}
```

Comment: The message ``syntax error on line 4, col 6: `    home:'``  suggests an error in your Yaml. Check `en.yml`, especially that you’re not using tabs and that your indentation is consistent.

Comment: I used tabs! Substituting them by blanks fixes the issue! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

```
syntax error on line 4, col 6: ` home:'
```

suggests an error in your Yaml. Check en.yml, especially that you’re not using tabs and that your indentation is consistent.